# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'reservation_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.8

I can't get through in my code. I have error indicating that '**reservation_id**' doesn't have a default value. 
This **reservation_id** of table **reservation_participate_details** is a foreign key from the parent table **reservation**'s id column. I wonder if there is something to do with the **hasMany** or **belongsTo** thing. I am not yet familiar deeply on laravel.

The **reservation** table should/has many rows in the **reservation_participate_details**. The process is working before but when I changed a column (reservation_participate_id) of **reservation_participate_details** into reservation_id and point it as a foreign key of **reservation**'s column **id**, it is now not working.

I have tried to put

```
    public function participateDetail()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ReservationParticipateDetail');
    }
```

into the **reservation**(parent) table and

```
    public function reservation()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Reservation');
    }
```

into the **reservation_participate_detail** table

I just need to save participate details into **reservation_participate_details**. Again, **reservation** table has many **reservation_participate_details**.

Comment: The error said that when you insert a row in `reservation_participate_details` table, you didn't set the value for `reservation_id` column.

Comment: @catcon yes, I understand that idea. I just want to know what am I missing here. I am new to laravel

Comment: @MDB can you please check in your table ? `reservation_id` is the primary key. so you have set AUTO_INCREMENT while creating the table ?

Comment: @MDB try adding `reservation_id` in corresponding model file if not present.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have changed the names of foreign key columns (not followed laravel default convention), you need to define those column names in relationship functions.

**reservation model**

```php
public function participateDetail()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ReservationParticipateDetail', 'reservation_id', 'id');
}
```

**reservation participate details model**

```php
public function reservation()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Reservation', 'reservation_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: I changed the column's foreign key using migrations. Sorry i did not mention it.

Comment: If you did not followed the laravel naming convention for columns, you have to define them like I mention in the answer.

Comment: hmm. I think I did followed the laravel's naming convention for columns. I think I am missing something here. I just don't know what.